# Code Error, not able to figure out

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

Modified Code:  Now giving error "Subscript out of range".

I am having the issue with the code below.

This code is making several copies of a file in the same folder.

Along with this, I added additional statements in the code that will allow the "file name" of the new file to get copied into a new sheet in the new workbook that has been created.

On running its giving an Error: `application defined or object defined error`

Can anyone tell me what I am missing from the code? Thanks much for your help.

```
    Sub CopyFile()
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim Subfolder As String
Dim Sourcefile As String
Dim Targetfile As String
Dim targetwb As Workbook
Dim targetsheet As Worksheet
Dim myFSO As Object

Subfolder = "J:\Temp\Data\Report\"
Sourcefile = "Hospital .xls" 'The original file name
Set myFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'loop from A2 to A53
i = 2
Do While ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value <> Empty
'determine Targetfilename
Targetfile = Subfolder & ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value & ".xls"
'copy file
myFSO.CopyFile Subfolder & Sourcefile, Targetfile, True 'true will overwrite existing files
i = i + 1
Loop
Set myFSO = Nothing
targetwb = Workbooks(Targetfile)
targetsheet = targetwb("Sheet12")
j = 2
Do While targetsheet.Cells(j, 3).Value <> Empty
targetsheet.Cells(j, 3).copy
targetsheet.Cells(4).Paste
j = j + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Which line gets an error?

Comment: What are you doing with the pastespecial?  You're using Transpose, but you're only copying a single cell.  If you just want to copy the value over, then just use `range1.Value = range2.Value`

Comment: @ Peter: It did not give me an option to hit debug which would highlight the line causing error.

Comment: maybe it's due to i is an `integer` and you have more > 1024 rows? Can you try declaring i as `long`

Comment: @ Larry: I only have 55 rows

Comment: `targetsheet.Cells(columnCount, "D")` <~~~ What kind of syntax is this?

Comment: @ Larry: I am still learning VBA. Sorry about the wierd syntax

Comment: Cells syntax (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196273.aspx)  I think you should use `targetsheet.Cells(columnCount, 4)` instead as @Sorceri posted below

Answer (score 2):

The issue is most likely with the line and the variable columnCount and the reference to "D".  See comments below about the values .Cells takes.  Updated this to reflect columnCount variable and changed "D" to 4 to represent the 4th column aka "D" :)

```
dim columnCount as Integer
columnCount = 10

targetsheet.Cells(columnCount, 4).End(xlUp).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
```

Comment: @Scrceri: If I remove columncount, still I am getting the same error: Set targetsheet = ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).copy
ActiveSheet.Cells("D1").Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

Comment: targetsheet.Cells(4).End(xlUp).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True....you are referencing the cell wrong.  Cells takes  a row and column number.  or you can add jsut the one to reflect a single cell in row 1